# Como passar um paramêtro de busca no retrofit com kotlin?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

Estou tentando utilizar a biblioteca Retrofit para fazer requisições HTTP para a API: [API Star War](https://swapi.co/api/people/), com a linguagem Kotlin, entretanto não sei como passar corretamente um parâmetro de busca para uma função da API.

Código da interface:

```
 @GET("people/?search=")
    fun getPersonagem(nome: String):Call<PersonagemList>
```

Já tentei dessa forma também:

```
@GET("people/?search={nome}")
    fun getPersonagem(@Path ("nome") nome: String):Call<PersonagemList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resultado ficou assim:

> @GET("people/")
>       fun getPersonagem(@Query("search") nome:String):Call PersonagemList

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, blza!?
Na versão 2 do retrofit os dados codificados por formulário são enviados quando `@FormUrlEncoded`. Cada par de valores-chave é anotado com `@Fiel` do nome e o objeto fornecendo o valor.
Faça no seguinte padrão:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("Tokencelular")
Call<TokenModel> gravaToken(@Field("tokenDevice") String tokenDevice); //e assim por diante
```

Nos métodos GET não é preciso o `@FormUrlEncoded`.

Para saber mais, visite a documentação: https://square.github.io/retrofit/ e vá no tópico **FORM ENCODED AND MULTIPART**

Abraços!